# Access 2007 SQL UNION with more than 2 queries raises error

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have the following query that runs perfectly on Acces 2007:

```
SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
```

I have several queries like this one that I want to "UNION". If I "UNION" just 2 queries it is working but when I try to "UNION more that 2, Access tells me that the number of columns in my queries are not equal.

I tried to "UNION" three times this same query like this (this way I am sure that the number of columns are the same in the three queries):

```
SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
```

But it is not working either.

Do you have any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Activity,A.id,A.ItemLeft,A.LeftRefLastRev,A.ItemRight,A.RightRefLastRev,A.Valid
FROM           
    (
        SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
        FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
        FROM ((ProjectReferences AS ProjectReferences_1 INNER JOIN ProjectRTMSystemRequirements ON ProjectReferences_1.Id = ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.reference) INNER JOIN ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds ON ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.Id = ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.SystemRequirement.Value) INNER JOIN ProjectReferences ON ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.reference = ProjectReferences.Id
    ) A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT "Concept" AS Activity, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.Id AS id, ProjectRTMAcquisitionNeeds.AcquisitionNeed AS ItemLeft, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences.title) AS LeftRefLastRev, ProjectRTMSystemRequirements.SystemRequirement AS ItemRight, (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM ProjectReferences AS PR WHERE PR.title = ProjectReferences_1.title) AS RightRefLastRev, IIf([ProjectReferences].[rev]=[LeftRefLastRev] And [ProjectReferences_1].[rev]=[RightRefLastRev],1,0) AS Valid
```

Comment: Try this above answer.

Comment: Thx but it raises the following error: "Reserved error (-3087); there is no message for this error"